# Database get rid of repeated attribute

Tags: mysql, database

So basically I have 3 tables: student, class, and enrollment.

```
CREATE TABLE class
    (`class_name` varchar(13), `class_id` int primary key)
;

INSERT INTO class
    (`class_name`, `class_id`)
VALUES
    ('math', 5697),
    ('science', 5768),
    ('computer', 6315),
    ('physical-ed', 6422),
    ('music', 7528),
    ('art', 7604),
    ('jrotc', 8797),
    ('culinary-arts', 8069)
;


CREATE TABLE student
    (`student_fname` varchar(8), `student_id` varchar(11) primary key)
;

INSERT INTO student
    (`student_fname`, `student_id`)
VALUES
    ('james', 'Vre94b3JpXO'),
    ('jim', 'JzqQ2zRVNm1'),
    ('jenny', 'xgqv9P42eYL'),
    ('kyle', 'QLNM0Wbyqk0'),
    ('kimberly', 'P2egAddWN0Q'),
    ('kayla', 'EGNDjWAreAy'),
    ('noah', 'bPeOyMMONGr'),
    ('nataly', '9Op53GGmqk5')
;

create table enrollment (
  `no` int(10),
  `student_id` varchar(11),
  `class_id` int,
  `semester` varchar(20),
  primary key (`student_id`, `class_id`, `semester`),
  foreign key (`student_id`) references student (`student_id`),
  foreign key (`class_id`) references class (`class_id`)
);

insert into enrollment values
(1, 'Vre94b3JpXO', 5697, 'Fall 2015'),
(2,'JzqQ2zRVNm1', 5697, 'Fall 2015'),
(3, 'xgqv9P42eYL', 5697, 'Fall 2015'),
(4, 'JzqQ2zRVNm1', 8069, 'Fall 2014'),
(5, 'xgqv9P42eYL', 8069, 'Fall 2014');
```

If I follow the query:

```
select * from student s 
join enrollment e on s.student_id = e.student_id 
join class c on c.class_id = e.class_id
```

I would get something like this:
[image]

How could I remove the redundant column like student_id and class_id?

This question is extended from the page:
[Table structure - Link one student with multiple classes id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32660125/table-structure-link-one-student-with-multiple-classes-id?lq=1)

and [demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/16e73b/13)

I have been using the joining method but I couldn't get what I wanted, thanks for your help.

Comment: `select s.*, e.*, c.class_name...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just specify the columns you want to see.

```
select s.student_fname, s.student_id,
e.no, e.class_id, e.semester, 
c.class_name,   
from 
student s join enrollment e 
on s.student_id = e.student_id 
join class c 
on c.class_id = e.class_id ;
```

Answer (score 3):

To answer this question, it might be nice to review some basics :

```
SELECT *
```

This `*` is to display all the columns from the table(s) you have selected

If you want to display only some columns, you have to specificly name it :

```
SELECT class_name, ...
```

But if you have some tables with the same column name, you have to specify the table name or alias :

```
SELECT c.class_name
 FROM mytable t 
 INNER JOIN class c ON c.id_table = t.id
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

`SELECT s.*
    ,e.no
    ,e.class_id
    ,e.semester
    ,c.class_name
FROM student s
INNER JOIN enrollment e ON s.student_id = e.student_id
INNER JOIN class c ON c.class_id = e.class_id`

In your select you can specify each column you'd like and thus what order.

```
SELECT e.no
,e.class_id
```

If you want all columns from a table you can do that table dot star like:

```
SELECT s.*
```

As you already have in the existing query you can simply do star to get all the columns:

```
SELECT *
```

Here is a good place to start for some basic `SELECT` tricks: https://www.techrepublic.com/article/sql-basics-select-statement-options/

On an aside, it can be helpful to use a site like: http://poorsql.com/ to help with your SQL formatting.