# Multi table inheritance in Laravel

Tags: laravel, inheritance, eloquent

I want just a simple example on how to have multi tables in database using Eloquent, for example :
I have a Model "Person", and there is 2 classes extending from this Model : Student and Teacher, and in database I don't want to have one table (persons), I want to have 2 tables (students and teachers).

How this is possible in Laravel (Eloquent), give me just the code of the three classes (Person, Student and Teacher).

Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not tested but should work:

[Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions)

`Person.php`

```
<?php 
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Person extends Model {
    // ...
}
```

`Student.php`

```
<?php 
namespace App;
class Student extends Person {
    $table = 'students';
    // ...
}
```

`Teacher.php`

```
<?php 
namespace App;
class Teacher extends Person {
    $table = 'teachers';
    // ...
}
```

---

*Migrations*

You can create the desired migrations as usual with `php artisan make:migration create_students_table --create=students`. Then migrate with `php artisan migrate`

```
<?php
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateStudentsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('students', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            // ...
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->softDeletes();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('students');
    }
}
```

---

**EDIT**

I don't know the background but maybe a trait is the better alternative.

Comment: Thanks I did not know about the $table variable, that was helpful. But what about migration files of this models, because when I execute the commande php artisan migrate, the tables teachers and students does not contain any columns !

Comment: you have to define you migration files as usual .. check the *migrations* edit

Comment: If I am going to define all columns in the migration file, then what is the purpose of inheritance between Person and Student ?

Comment: I dont know your app / structure - maybe for different methods, relations and stuff. You could also use the same table?! I would recomend to [normalize](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5135889/how-to-normalize-a-sql-database)